# The Invoice and order email not received

Tags: orders, email, invoice, cron, order-email

I tried for an hour, but I can't find the correct solution for my problem. My Magento version is 1.9.2.2 and updated security patch. Now after placing the order the order and invoice mail can't be received (admin, customer). After checking the the error log below this message is shown:

```
    2016-02-12T14:36:06+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:379
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(513): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('2', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#2 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1356): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#3 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1371): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail(true)
#4 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#5 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->emailAction()
#6 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
#7 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/html/pondevolution/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/www/html/pondevolution/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

Checking the email Queue after a couple of hours: wait in cron, added `$emailQueue->send()` 
after `$message = $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();`  called in

```
/var/www/html/pondevolution/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
```

The queue mails are sent immediately.

How can I check the cron job is running or not and how can I send the email via cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best extension for working with Magento cronjobs is [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler). This extension adds a graphical overview about your cronjobs to the admin backend and you can also see the result in the list view.

You can also manually start cronjobs from there, either via manually scheduling them or the "run now" functionality (which needs to be activated seperatly).

In addition to this: Make sure your cronjobs on system level (`crontab -l`) are set up correctly so they run regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to the server you can also do

```
crontab -l
```

And you should have a cron setup for the cron.php in the root of your magento site.

Alternatively you could also look in your database at the cron_schedule table and see if the crons are firing in there, more specifically check that the 'core_email_queue_send_all' jobcode is appearing there.